# .php file won't read styles from .css file

Tags: php, css, ubuntu-15.04

I am making a .php website (text editor, on Ubuntu) and I'm trying to include style.css with html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" href="style.css" />
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

which is between  tags. For some reason it won't work (neither in Mozilla nor in Chrome). It does work for other php websites that I created before and copied into /var/www/html but not for this one. I've checked other threads and articles on the web, it's not about directories... No idea.

Perhaps I could ask for an advice?

Comment: use your browser's debugger... (press F12). and php wont read it anway because it generates the html. the browser reads style files

Comment: it won't display anything helpful, no css code although it is in the file

Comment: relevance to php is? show your PHP code

Comment: there's no php code so far. the relevance is that the browser can see the styles in css file if the index file is saved as .html, but it won't see it as .php. I want to include php code later on... does it make any difference?

Comment: check your configuration then. If `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` works, then it's a path issue.

Comment: do you just open the php file directly without using a server?

Comment: another thing is how you're trying to access those php files. Are you using `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php` :? those are 2 different animals altogether.

Comment: well, it seems obvious so I did not mention... yes, I have apache2 installed and I access the websites using localhost/.../index.php.

Comment: `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>` does work fine. what about the path? the .css file is in the same directory as the index.php file...

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: David, not really, it's not accessible from outside...

Comment: Try adding a couple of styles in the head using `<style></style>`, does your browser parse that?

Comment: David, yes it does parse internal style sheet in the head.

Comment: Have you checked your permissions for the CSS file? If your working locally then that would be my best guess. Another thing to try is to replicate the page on an accessible web server, it will be easier for us to debug.

Comment: the owner (me) can read and write. the rest can do nothing... I don't have access to a server at the moment.

Comment: it was about permissions, I set read&write everywhere and allowed to execute the file as a program and it worked. Thank you for help... unfortunately I can't vote for a comment...

Comment: No problem. You should probably add the solution as an answer in case it may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was about style.css file permissions - only the owner of the file could read&write and the rest could do nothing. I changed all the permissions to read&write and checked 'allow to execute the file as program' and it worked fine.